# How to use already created img on qemu

Tags: vmware, qemu, kvm

I use VMware and then install qemu on it.

Create img.

```
$ sudo qemu-img create -f qcow2 mini3.img 5G
```

Then create a virtual machine.

```
$ sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -enable-kvm -hda mini3.img -cdrom ./minix_R3.3.0-588a35b.iso -boot d

qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
```

[image]

And I turn off this virtual machine and then start the created virtual machine.

```
$ sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -enable-kvm -hda mini3.img 

qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
```

But no success.

[image]

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that in the first run your OS is booting from cdrom image (minix_R3.3.0-588a35b.iso). In the second run you removed it, and there is only a hard drive image (mini3.img). You probably failed to properly install the OS in the first run to your hard drive image.